# How to run a query on the view in Hive?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

We are running a simple select on the view (which contains lot of data) and we are getting "GC overhead limit exceeded, out of memory error. We want to run this query so that report that runs on top of this view can work. It runs on Tez.

The query runs for 4+ hours and fails.  Is there any way we can run this query, like some set options?

Query

```
select * from inc_cts.v_report_pub_view;
```

Error message -

```
    TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=
» Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
  at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:204)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
  ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:182)
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
  ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.listRealloc(FlatRowContainer.java:259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.add(FlatRowContainer.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:133)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
  ... 4 more

TaskAttempt 1 killed
TaskAttempt 2 killed
TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=
» Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
  at or
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:182)
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
  ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.listRealloc(FlatRowContainer.java:259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.add(FlatRowContainer.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:133)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
  ... 4 more

TaskAttempt 4 killed
TaskAttempt 5 failed, info=
» Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
  at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:204)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
  ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:182)
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
  ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.listRealloc(FlatRowContainer.java:259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.add(FlatRowContainer.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:133)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
  ... 4 more

TaskAttempt 6 failed, info=
» Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
  at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
  at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reduce operator initialization failed
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:204)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
  ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.init(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:182)
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
  ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.listRealloc(FlatRowContainer.java:259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.FlatRowContainer.add(FlatRowContainer.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:133)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
  ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the log, exception is `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in MapJoin HashTableLoader.

check you current settings and increase accordingly:

```
set hive.tez.container.size=4096MB; 
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=1370MB --recommended one third of container size
```

Try to use memory optimized hashtable:

```
set hive.mapjoin.optimized.hashtable=true;
set hive.mapjoin.optimized.hashtable.wbsize=10485760; --Default Value (10 * 1024 * 1024)
--Optimized hashtable uses a chain of buffers to store data. This is one buffer size.
```

Finally, if nothing helps, you can switch off mapjoin:

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply. i can see hive.tez.container.size = 11264 MB in ambari, so is it always applied or thats the max that can apply.

Comment: @akashsharma check in hive session `set hive.tez.container.size;`